# After Executing a exe from command line command line should wait for the completion of exe

Tags: c++, command-line, c++builder-xe3

I have a executable in which some command line options are provided to run it in a silent mode.
But when i run the executable from the command prompt with command line options it didn't wait for the completion of executable.

I want that it should wait for the completion of execution of exe.

I don't want to add any other parameter in command prompt.
I want to handle this in executable.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Comment: It should work in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be handled in the executable. The console is launching the executable and not waiting for it to exit.  That is a console issue, not an executable issue.  You need to use the console's `start` command to run the executable so you can use the command's `/wait` parameter:

```
start /wait myapp.exe /silent
```

Or else use a batch file to run your executable, and then have the console run the batch file.  A batch file waits for each command to complete, and the console waits for a batch file to complete.