# Monitoring completion of a task in the command line (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, command-line

I am using Python (2.7) to run another executable via the command line. The executable has output that is shown on the command line, but it is a "black box" in the sense that I cannot alter the code of the program. Is there a way to monitor the executable's output, to tell when it has completed? I read in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021364/after-executing-a-exe-from-command-line-command-line-should-wait-for-the-complet) that

> The console is launching the executable and not waiting for it to exit.

I'm guessing this is the case regardless of what language you use to call the executable via the command line?

Comment: You mean you just want to wait for the executable to complete, and you want to capture the output? If so, you can just use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: More specifically, I'd like to wait for the executable to complete, so that I can signal another portion of my code to run to analyze the results. The output of the executable consists of files written to a specific folder. I guess I could always monitor the number of files in the folder, but even then, I'd have to wait until the last file finished being written to.

Comment: Then just use [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks for the suggestion -- this is likely correct. I tried subprocess when trying to run the program earlier, but had switched to using `os.system(command)` instead. I'm trying `subprocess` now.